# How do I move the toolbar in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I move the toolbar in IntelliJ from the Top Right corner to the Top Left?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 104, accepted):

click on Main Menu | View | Toolbar

Comment: There was weeping here, and gnashing of teeth.  Google did not seem to know this.  Thanks

Comment: Note that the toolbar, when shown on the top right, lives in the same horizontal space as the navigation bar, so you need to enable that, and disable the toolbar, for things to look as normal.

Comment: yeah for some reason I like it better w/o the toolbar

Answer (score 56):

*I'm writing this answer because I wanted the opposite. One day IntelliJ suddenly started aligning the buttons to the left.*

There are at least two toolbars in IntelliJ:

- The Toolbar which is aligned to the left,
- and the Navigation bar which is aligned to the right.

The buttons of both toolbars can be customized independently.

Therefore, in order to show the toolbar one side or the other, press `CTRL + SHIFT + A` and then type either `View Toolbar` or `View Navigation bar`.

Comment: So hiding the toolbar puts the edit configurations on the right there. Odd, but works! Thank you.

Comment: dear god thank you, i was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it moved

Comment: Seems not to work anymore.... I disabled showing Toolbar and when I enabled it again it's now alligned to the left... I want it back to the right, is it somehow possible to align it to the right again?

Answer (score 10):

Previous answers didn't work for me because in mac `CTRL + SHIFT + A` does nothing and `View -> Toolbar` doesn't exist, actually it's `View -> Appearance -> Toolbar`.

In mac, for Android Studio 4.2 (it changed the toolbars/navigation when updating) you can right click the Navigation bar (the one that shows the current file location at the top left) and hide it, untick `"Show Navigation bar"`.

Then, toggle the Toolbar, `View -> Appearance -> Toolbar` on and off, this will show the icons to the left, as in my previous instance of Android Studio.

Now you can re-enable the Navigation bar and it will show below the Toolbar.