# Customize Intellij top menu to include debugger icons

Tags: intellij-idea, toolbar

I would like the debugger menu (with the step over and step into etc) buttons up in the top menu next to the run/debug/stop buttons. Is there any way to make this happen? I can move then entire debugging pane up top. But that is not what I want. I just want the icons up top like other IDE's have.

this is a different question than [How do I move the toolbar in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184766/how-do-i-move-the-toolbar-in-intellij) 
I am not asking how to move the existing toolbar, I'm asking how to add the debug buttons to the toolbar up top.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at the moment. Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

### 2022 UPDATE

It is possible now as JetBrains has added highly-customizable functionality for controlling commands in menus and toolbars.

- For Windows/Linux: `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars`
- For Mac: `IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars`

Additional info [on the IntelliJ website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/menus-and-toolbars-appearance-settings.html).